# ClipPath hides the original shape - d3 ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm a newbie to D3 and ReactJS, and trying to clip circle with a straight line, but could not get how it works. I have this HTML code to draw image;

```
  <div >

          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  className="clip-path" ref={this.attachCircle.bind(this)}>

          </svg>
        </div>
```

here is my function to draw image;

```
attachCircle = (svgRef:SVGElement) => {

const svg = d3.select(svgRef);
// draw a circle

  svg.append("circle")            // shape it as an ellipse
    .attr("cx", 100)            // position the x-centre
    .attr("cy", 80)            // position the y-centre
    .attr("r", 80)            // set the x radius
        .attr("fill", "SteelBlue")
}
```

and it results in this way;

[image]

but as soon as I add `clipPath` to circle;

```
svg.append("clipPath")       // define a clip path
    .attr("id", "clip") // give the clipPath an ID
  .append("circle")            // shape it as an ellipse
    .attr("cx", 100)            // position the x-centre
    .attr("cy", 80)            // position the y-centre
    .attr("r", 80)            // set the x radius
        .attr("fill", "SteelBlue")
```

it shows nothing on the screen. It is not drawing any circle or anything.

> Can anyone explain why is it so??  or What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `use`

```
 <use clip-path="url(#clip)" xlink:href="#clip" fill="red" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Comment: I've to do it in JS file, not in html